# how to initialize an array of std::vector?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, stl

As we all know, it's normal to initialize an array of `int` like this:

```
int intAry[] = {7, 8, 9};
```

So, I want to know, how can initialize an array of std::vector `in the same way`(just in the initial list):

```
typedef std::vector<int> type;
type vecAry[] = {vec1, vec2, vec3};
```

I know it's legal to write code as fllows, now my question how to initialize vecAry in one line of code:

```
type vec1;
type vec2;
type vec3;
type vecAry = {vec1, vec2, vec3};
```

Comment: And why would you need array of vector ?

Comment: @0x499602D2, are you kidding me? you can't compile in C++.

Comment: @Hitesh Vaghani, why ask my requirement? I want to implement design pattern in my code.

Comment: Because vector of vectors is always there.

Comment: in your post should be `type vecAry[] = {vec1, vec2, vec3};` ?

Comment: @HiteshVaghani: Why use a vector (with the overhead of memory allocation and an extra level of indirection) when an array will suffice? Especially in C++03, where vectors are more awkward to initialise.

Comment: @MikeSeymour yeah you are right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++11,

```
type vecAry[] {{},{},{}};
```

or if you want non-empty vectors

```
type vecAry[] {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
```

If you're stuck in the past, you can initialise it with empty vectors:

```
type vecAry[] = {type(), type(), type()};
```

but you can't initialise it with arbitrary values without some kind of helper like those in the [Boost Assignment library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html):

```
type vecAry[] = {list_of(1)(2)(3), list_of(4)(5)(6), list_of(7)(8)(9)};
```