# How to use both std::vector and std::array at the same time?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, stl

I am using something like this:

```
std::vector<std::array<double, 3>> myarray;
```

but when I want to add new elements into the array, I try to use

```
myarray.push_back({0, 0 ,0});
```

It doesn't compile with VS2012.

So how can I use std::array as an element of std::vector?

Thank you.

Comment: `std::vector` does not have a `pushback` member. Please post real code.

Comment: You are missing `_` in the middle of `push_back`. Otherwise, some better compilers accept this code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to initialize an array of std::vector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17855819/how-to-initialize-an-array-of-stdvector)

Comment: Compiles at http://ideone.com/xUZmpw

Comment: -2? There is nothing wrong with this question. OP states the compiler and submits an sscce. Problem boils down to a compiler masquerading as C++11 compliant but is missing many of the features.

Comment: Thank you all. It is my typing mistake. already corrected.

Comment: @Bathsheba (I didn't vote) This is not an sscce. It had a typo and is still missing the includes and a function. Also, AFAIK MSVC is one of the very few compilers that does not pretend to be a C++11 compiler (value of __cplusplus), I don't know why you are calling it a masquerade.

Comment: OP can you please post the error message

Answer (score 2):

You're out of luck I'm afraid: VS2012 does not support brace initialisation.

Note that your code is valid C++11.

Comment: Thank you. but how can I add an element of std::array type to std::vectort within VS2012

Comment: A `std::array`, unlike normal arrays, can be copied as a single value. Declare a local variable of type `std::array` and pass it to `push_back`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure the missing _ in push_back was a typo.

The problem is VS2012. Use VS2013 or a compiler that supports C++11, or initialise a new element explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it the long way.

```
std::array<double, 3> a; // Maybe you can use brace initialization here? Not sure
a[0] = 1;
a[1] = 5;
a[2] = 0;
myarray.push_back(a);
```